# Oauth2 using LDAP form based Authentication

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

Is there a good example of Oauth2 - Implicit Grant ,Spring Boot that uses LDAP based form Authentication. I am new to Oauth 2 and finding it difficult to understand how it works. I understand some part of theory - grant type, access token and the flow but find it complicated to implement.  I have a  spring boot app that i would like to secure with OAUTH2 . Please provide me some pointers.